# Continuous functions "send neighboring points into neighboring points"

Tags: continuity, intuition

In "The elements of real analysis" by Bartle there is written:

*Sometimes it is said that a continuous function is one which "sends neighboring points into neighboring points".*(A-version) *This intuitive phrase is to be avoided if it leads one to believe that the image of a neighborhood of a point $t$ need be a neighborhood of $f(t)$.*(B-version) *Consider $f(x)=|x|$ at $x=0$.*

I know how to prove that it is continuous using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

The question is about what is the difference between A-version and B-version? For me both sound exactly the same.

Maybe the textbook wants to say something like this:

Look at the point $0\in D(f)$. There are neighborhood points from left and right side which are in the domain of this function. Then look at $0\in R(f)$. It has not neighborhood points from left side in $R(f)$. So we can say that this function "sends neighboring points into neighboring points" (in the sense that the close points here are close there) but we can not say that the image of a neighborhood of a point $t$ need be a neighborhood of $f(t)$.

Do I understand it correct?

EDIT: I have got the answer (from Amit). The reason for this question was my ignorance of the language (I mixed up "neighboring points" and "points in the neighborhood").

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Image of an open neighbourhood is not necessarily open.

Comment: @Amit Oh! I read about it somewhere but did not know that this mean exactly this. Thank you!

Comment: As an aside, there is a sense in which we can make the "intuitive phrase" precise. If we write $\overline{A}$ to mean the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)) of $A$, then $f : X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if $f(\overline{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)}$ for every $A \subseteq X$. That is, if and only if points "close to $A$" get set to points "close to $f(A)$" for every subset $A$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thank you! What if we do the next thing? We define function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ by $f( x)=|x|$ and we consider the interval $[0,\infty)$ as metric space $[0,\infty)$ with the euclidean metric.  Then in this setting we can say that the image of open sets is open sets. Because $[0,1)$ for example is open in this space. Is it correct?

Comment: yes, that's right ^_^

Comment: Though it is still not inevitable that the image of an open set is open in the image of $f$. For example look at $x(1-x)$ and look at the image of $(0,1)$. The closure property mentioned earlier is the actual way to formalize this intuitive statement.

Comment: @Ian Thank you! But I do not understand what do you want to say by this example. It is the function f:R→(−∞,1/4] defined by f(x)=x(1−x). The image of (0,1) is (0,1/4]. If we consider the range of this function, in other words (−∞,1/4] as the metric space, then (0,1/4] is open. Am I correct?

Comment: Sorry, I needed an example with more than one local maximum, one higher than the other. Then the image of a small enough open neighborhood of the local maximum will not be open in the image. For example, look at a neighborhood of the positive maximum of $-x^4+x^2/2-0.1x$. The range is $(-\infty,M_L)$ ($M_L$ being the value of the left peak) and the image of the neighborhood will be some interval of the form $(a,M_R)$ ($M_R$ being the value of the right peak).

Comment: And I messed the explanation up again, I meant $(a,M_R]$ at the end.

Comment: @Ian Thank you!